swipper.js coverflow effect like sonar io
import {
  Navigation,
  Pagination,
  Scrollbar,
  A11y,
  EffectCoverflow,
} from "swiper/modules";

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { useSwiper } from "swiper/react";
// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import "swiper/css/scrollbar";

const AlbumCarousel = () => {
  return (
    <Swiper
      effect={"coverflow"}
      grabCursor={true}
      centeredSlides={true}
      coverflowEffect={{
        rotate: 15,
        depth: 300,
        modifier: 1,
        stretch: 0,
      }}
      simulateTouch
      cssMode
      loop={true}
      className="w-full h-72 p-4 swiper_container"
      modules={[Navigation, EffectCoverflow, Pagination, A11y]}
      pagination={{ clickable: true }}
      spaceBetween={-10}
      slidesPerView={4}
      navigation
      onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
      onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}
    >
      <SwiperSlide
        className={` h-64 bg-red-900 rounded-lg flex border border-black justify-center items-center flex-col w-fit  ${"swiper_slide"}`}
      >
        <div className="flex flex-col w-36">
          <div className="flex justify-start items-center w-full">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-center w-full  items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-end w-full items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide
        className={` h-64 bg-red-900 rounded-lg flex border border-black justify-center items-center flex-col w-fit  ${"swiper_slide"}`}
      >
        <div className="flex flex-col w-36">
          <div className="flex justify-start items-center w-full">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-center w-full  items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-end w-full items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide
        className={` h-64 bg-red-900 rounded-lg flex border border-black justify-center items-center flex-col w-fit  ${"swiper_slide"}`}
      >
        <div className="flex flex-col w-36">
          <div className="flex justify-start items-center w-full">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-center w-full  items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-end w-full items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide
        className={` h-64 bg-red-900 rounded-lg flex border border-black justify-center items-center flex-col w-fit  ${"swiper_slide"}`}
      >
        <div className="flex flex-col w-36">
          <div className="flex justify-start items-center w-full">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-center w-full  items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-end w-full items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide
        className={` h-64 bg-red-900 rounded-lg flex border border-black justify-center items-center flex-col w-fit  ${"swiper_slide"}`}
      >
        <div className="flex flex-col w-36">
          <div className="flex justify-start items-center w-full">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-center w-full  items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-end w-full items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide
        className={` h-64 bg-red-900 rounded-lg flex border border-black justify-center items-center flex-col w-fit  ${"swiper_slide"}`}
      >
        <div className="flex flex-col w-36">
          <div className="flex justify-start items-center w-full">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-center w-full  items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-end w-full items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide
        className={` h-64 bg-red-900 rounded-lg flex border border-black justify-center items-center flex-col w-fit  ${"swiper_slide"}`}
      >
        <div className="flex flex-col w-36">
          <div className="flex justify-start items-center w-full">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-center w-full  items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-end w-full items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide
        className={` h-64 bg-red-900 rounded-lg flex border border-black justify-center items-center flex-col w-fit  ${"swiper_slide"}`}
      >
        <div className="flex flex-col w-36">
          <div className="flex justify-start items-center w-full">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-center w-full  items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-end w-full items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide
        className={` h-64 bg-red-900 rounded-lg flex border border-black justify-center items-center flex-col w-fit  ${"swiper_slide"}`}
      >
        <div className="flex flex-col w-36">
          <div className="flex justify-start items-center w-full">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-center w-full  items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-end w-full items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide
        className={` h-64 bg-red-900 rounded-lg flex border border-black justify-center items-center flex-col w-fit  ${"swiper_slide"}`}
      >
        <div className="flex flex-col w-36">
          <div className="flex justify-start items-center w-full">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-center w-full  items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-end w-full items-center">
            <span>Item</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
  );
};

export default AlbumCarousel;

I am trying to create a carousal effect like sonar.io , view this demo here , most of it is working exactly how I liked , but when we move the carousel the main middle image should scale and other slides should de-scale , if I increase the depth , it will work but the size of the main swipper carousel will decrease and there is no way of fixing it
I've tried everything even asking AI but most of them are stupid and dosent work, the active slide should be large and the non active slides should be small
